# WebStorm: lock/unlock files and folders

Tags: intellij-idea, tfs, version-control, webstorm

I am using JetBrains WebStorm. I want to lock files so other user can't checkout that locked file. This locking functionality works in IntelliJ IDEA but not in WebStorm.

How to lock files in WebStorm?

> there is option of lock/unlock in WebStorm, but its not working in
>   WebStorm.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce this issue on my side, seems it's an issue with the [TFS integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578-tfs-integration) plugin.

I have submitted the issue with comments added in the [TFS Integration plugin page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578-tfs-integration), you can also track the issue there add comments to push the dev team to fix it in future.